# [System.IO.StreamReader].Open() method failing for .ini file

Tags: powershell, text, streamreader, ini

I'm trying to script some text editing in a `.ini` file. Contained in about ~100 archives files.
Not trying to do anything complicated (for a number of reasons), nothing a `$text -replace` wouldn't be able to do.

Let's say I have defined a `$innerpath = "YYYY/XXX.ini"`, where `XXX.ini` is the file I'm trying to edit, and `YYYY` the `<< inner path >>` that is common to all the archives.

I loop through all the archive files, but it seems the `.ini` files cannot be opened the way I do it.

```
foreach ($f in $files) {
    # The zip file to be updated
    $file = $f
    Write-Log "Editing following file : $f" "INFO" $logfile

    # Load ZipFile (Compression.FileSystem) if necessary
    try {
        $null = [IO.Compression.ZipFile]
    } catch {
        [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.IO.Compression.FileSystem')
    }

    # Open zip file with update mode (Update, Read, Create -- are the options)
    try {
        $fileZip = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::Open($file, 'Update')
    } catch {
        throw "Another process has locked the '$file' file."
        Write-Log "Another process has locked the '$file' file." "ERROR" $logfile
        Write-Log "Another process has locked the '$file' file."
        continue
    }

    # Finding the specific file within the zip file
    try {
        $fileZip.Entries | Where-Object { $_.FullName -match "$innerpath" }
    } catch {
        Write-Log "Could not find $filepath\$innerpath in $f , have you used anti-slash instead of slash ?" "WARN" $logfile
        Write-Log "Could not find $filepath\$innerpath in $f , have you used anti-slash instead of slash "
        continue
    }
    pause
    # If needed, read the contents of specific file to $text and release the file so to use streamwriter later
    try {
        $desiredFile = [System.IO.StreamReader]($fileZip.Entries | Where-Object { $_.FullName -match "$innerpath" }).Open()
        $text = $desiredFile.ReadToEnd()
        $desiredFile.Close()
        $desiredFile.Dispose()
    } catch {
        Write-Log "Could not read $f/$innerpath in $f " "WARN" $logfile
        Write-Log "Could not read $f/$innerpath in $f "
        continue
    }
```

My problem is rather simple :

```
$desiredFile = [System.IO.StreamReader]($fileZip.Entries | Where-Object { $_.FullName -match "$innerpath" }).Open()
```

is popping that error message :

```
Impossible d'appeler une méthode dans une expression Null.
Au caractère C:\Users\pfournet\Documents\Factory\BulkPrefEditor\BulkPrefEditor.ps1:150 : 5
+ ...             $desiredFile = [System.IO.StreamReader]($fileZip.Entries  ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation : (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

This is French for *"Impossible to call a method on a null expression"* or something like that.

Thing is I'm blaming this on the .ini extension, since I tried with :

`$innerpath = "YYYY/test.txt"`

and the script worked fine.

Comment: What type is `$f` and therefore `$file`? What do you get when you type `$file | get-member`? I tried it and my `$files` are from type FileInfo and if I use `$fileZip = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::Open($files[0].FullName, 'Update')` I am able to get the `$desiredFile` in exactly the same way as you do..

Comment: get -member logs : **System.String LinkType{get=GetLinkType;} System.String Mode{get=Mode;} System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]** Unfortunately, i can see an exception when trying to Open like you said : Exception lors de l'appel de «Open» avec «2» argument(s): «Impossible de trouver l'enregistrement End of Central Directory.»
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidDataException

Comment: Instead of cramming multiple statements into one line, separate the statements from each other and inspect their individual results: `$entries = $fileZip.Entries; $inifile = $entries | Where-Object { $_.FullName -match "$innerpath" }; $reader = [IO.StreamReader]$inifile; $desiredFile = $reader.Open()`.

Comment: The problem seems to be that your `$file` is just a string and not a `FileInfo`.. Get your file with `Get-ChildItem` or something similar

Comment: Are you sure any of your zipfile entries match the ```where-object``` filter? I can reproduce your exception with something like ```( @("aaa", "bbb") | where-object { $_ -match "xxx" } ).xyz()``` because the entire ```( ... )``` value is ```$null``` so you're trying to call the ```xyz()``` method on a null expression.

Comment: That's what I've been doing                                                                              `$filespath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
                                                       $files = Get-ChildItem $filespath`

Comment: @mclayton I believe they do, since the error pops up _"Could not read"_ instead of _"Could not find"_, which is the 2nd **"Where"** filter. And it works with a test.txt positionned in the same directory as the xxx.ini

Comment: Guys, I found it : I tested with test.ini and it worked. Then I deleted xxx.ini from the archive, added it back, and it worked. So I have to troubleshoot this now. But the code I pasted works.